# Allow One View to Support Multiple Orientations While Others Do Not iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, orientation

I have a situation where I have multiple views controlled via `UITabBarController`. One of those views is controlled via a `UINavigationController`. The application should only support Portrait for all views... except one single solitary view. This view is pushed onto the stack of the navigation controller and should allow both portrait AND landscape.

I've tried every solution that I can think of but, either the solution just doesn't work or worse is completely unpredictable.

Has anybody solved this issue in a clean way?

Comment: Did you try using UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification to receive UIDeviceOrientation changes and react accordingly (rotation transform) ? It would help if you listed all the solutions you thought of and why they did not work for you (I suppose that you did actually try all sorts of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation combinations).

Comment: by the way - is the view you want to rotate managed by a view controller? UIViews do not rotate by themselves, their controllers rotate them. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324394/iphone-subview-rotation-problem

Comment: @magma yes, they are in the controllers. The problem is apparently based upon the use of the UITabBarController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view's controller that you present either using `presentModalViewController` OR `pushViewController` should support any orientation, using this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

With this method, when you present your controller in landscape orientation, it will correctly appear in landscape orientation, too.

Comment: Ended up just reimplementing the view as a modal view. Messing with the tabbarcontroller ended up being a rabbit hole to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You have to implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for your `UITabBarController` and return YES for all the orientations you want to support across all your view controllers. And in the same method for all the other view controllers return YES only for the orientations you want to support in each of those view controllers.

To implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for your UITabBarController, you could subclass UITabBarController, but an easier way is to implement a category on UITabBarController and just implement that method:

```
@implementation UITabBarController(orientation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation
{
    return YES; // or whatever you need
}

@end
```

NB: Typed into a web browser; not compiled. :-)

You can put this right in your app delegate .m file at the end.

What I found was that UITabBarController returns YES only for portrait, which apparently also affects all the subordinate view controllers. In my case I had one subordinate view controller that I wanted to support both portrait and landscape and this solved it.

Comment: Ah, that was the core to my problem. I created a custom UITabBarController and overrode shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to pass the value of the visible view controller. However, still have an issue that when switching back to another view it doesn't force Portrait if the device is in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the navigation inside of a tab bar, then the only option is to present the particular view as a modal view (tab bar requires all views to support the orientation to autorotate). So basically the single view controller, that needs landscape should implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
      if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
          // Create the landscape version of the view and present it modally
      }

      return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Then dismiss the modal view in the modal view controller's same method, by detecting portrait orientation and using the method for the parent `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: animated]`

Answer (score 0):

For iOS-6 , I have done this , it is running greatly

```
(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

This will help you....