# iOS 7 unlock device orientation in video playback

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, device-orientation

My entire app is locked in portrait orientation but when a video is played I wanna allow all orientations just for the video playback.

Storyboard:
TabBarController --> NavigationController --> MyVideosController --> MyVideoPlayerController

This is one of many I've tried:
[Allow One View to Support Multiple Orientations While Others Do Not iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735060/allow-one-view-to-support-multiple-orientations-while-others-do-not-iphone)

The problem is that I never even reach into this method in my MyVideoPlayerController.m:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

Comment: That method is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience just about every suggestion you will find on here won't work for you.  What you are going to want to do is (if you are using storyboards) add another navigation controller and a view controller.  You will push the 2nd navigation controller modally and lock it to the orientation you desire.  This way your video player can "pop up" and be in the orientation(s) you want.

Its really annoying.

An alternative (which I don't really suggest) is that you can turn on AutoLayout and perhaps try the IOS6 version.

Comment: Sorry for late reply Jeef. This was actually part of the solution, thank you! The reason It did´t work before was that the TabBarController locked the orientation for all it´s childcontrollers. By subclass TabBarController and set the orientation to portrait, push my mediaPlayerView modally (as you proposed) with all orientation allowed, made it work.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS-6 , I have done this , it is running greatly

```
(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code, add it to your class it's working for me:

```
#pragma mark - Orientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: This solution almost worked for me. supportedInterfaceOrientations
and shouldAutorotate gets called but then the device freezes. In my "General>Deployment Info" I have "Portrait" selected for the application. This causes the app to freeze. If I uncheck the "Portrait" selection the app dont freeze but the shouldAutorotate method never gets called. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Its when I set - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate to return NO that causes the app to crash.

Comment: put the code that support orientation in your MyVideoPlayerController and when you get back to your viewController use the same code but only use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait for it, and in the General>Deployment Info check only the portrait and uncheck the other options, i have the same case in my app and it's working fine without any freezing.. i think something else is making your app freez